# Fragment transition appears from right to left, disappears from left to right (back to the point it starts from)

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment-transitions

I want to reach a specific fragment transition behaviour ,as I mention in the question, I want my fragment to appears from the right and disappears in the same direction back to the point it starts from..
These are my xml animations :

right_to_left.xml :

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<translate
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromXDelta="100%"
    android:fromYDelta="0%"
    android:toXDelta="0%"
    android:toYDelta="0%" />
```

left_to_right.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromXDelta="0%"
    android:fromYDelta="0%"
    android:toXDelta="-100%"
    android:toYDelta="0%" />
```

and here are the different ways that I've tried to achieve the fragment animation :

When the fragment appears :

```
  productHolder.fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putSerializable(Utils.productDetailsKey, productPojo);
                ProductDetailsFragment productDetailsFragment = new ProductDetailsFragment();
                productDetailsFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.product_animation_enter, R.anim.product_animation_enter);
                transaction.add(R.id.newContainer, productDetailsFragment);
                transaction.commit();
                MainActivity.transparent.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.blackTransparent));


            }
        });
```

When the fragment disappears method 1 :

```
 fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.product_animation_exit, R.anim.product_animation_exit);
                transaction.remove(ProductDetailsFragment.this);
                transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
                MainActivity.transparent.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);


            }
        });
```

When the fragment disappears method 2 :

```
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.product_animation_exit);
                    animation.setDuration(getResources().getInteger(android.R.integer.config_mediumAnimTime));
                    animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                            try {
                                FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                                transaction.remove(ProductDetailsFragment.this);
                                transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
                                MainActivity.transparent.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);

                            } catch (Exception e) {
                            }

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                        }
                    });

                    getView().startAnimation(animation);
                }
            });
```

unfortunately none of those worked as I expect, 
May this image can explain more what I want : [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bWhL6.jpg)
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest, first you make a working solution the first part of your problem, that is switching between fragments, and then you add the second part, which is the animation.

**1. Switching fragments**

In your XML layout file you take out everything belonging to the fragments and add a `Framelayout`.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

In your code you get a reference to the `FrameLayout` like so:

```
int containerId = R.id.fragment_container;
```

Then you have two methods, one for adding the first fragment and one for switching back and forth between the two.

The add method goes like this:

```
void addFrag(int containerId, Fragment firstFragment){
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(containerId, firstFragment);
        transaction.commit();
}
```

The replace method goes like this:

```
void replaceFrag(int containerId, Fragment newFragment){
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(containerId, newFragment);
        transaction.commit();
}
```

As long as you pass the right fragment, you can use this method for replacing any of your fragments with the other one. **Edit** You can also use the `replaceFrag` method *only*, even for adding a fragment to the container for the first time. **End of edit**

**2. Animation**

That's really the easy part. You don't need to make your own XML, since sliding animations are built into Android (so use the exact IDs I am providing here). All you have to do is to add *one line of code before you add or replace your fragments*:

```
transaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
```

**Edit** Since these built-in animations start from 50%, however, they don't look too nice, in my opinion. You can simply use your XMLs:

transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.left_to_right, R.anim.right_to_left);

**End of Edit**